# Is it possible to factor $x^2-6x+7$ over $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: factoring

None of the online calculators seem to give me an answer.

I am trying to find the values for x. How do I do this again?

$$x^2-6x = -7$$

Then what?

Comment: Use [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2-6x%2B7). It gives you $-(x+\sqrt{2}+3)(x+\sqrt{2}-3)$. Just a sidenote, since you said no online calculators factor it, so the calculators you've been using aren't decent.

Answer (score 5):

$$
x^2-6x+7=(x^2-6x+9)-2=(x-3)^2-(\sqrt{2})^2=(x-3-\sqrt{2})(x-3+\sqrt{2}).
$$

Comment: i.e. complete the square (same as the proof of the quadratic formula).

Comment: @BillDubuque Agreed. I however usually prefer self-contained answers that refer to as few "named" results as possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it *is* possible, you *know* this since the [**discriminant**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant) is greater than $0$:
$$\Delta=b^2-4ac=36-4\cdot 1\cdot 7=8,$$
being the coefficients $a=1$, $b=-6$, $c=7$.
Follows that $\sqrt{\Delta}=2\sqrt{2}$ and
$$x_{1,2}=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{\Delta}}{2a}=3\pm\sqrt{2}.$$
Now,
$$
\begin{align}
x^2-6x+7&=(x-x_1)(x-x_2)=\\
&=(x-(3+\sqrt{2}))(x-(3-\sqrt{2}))=\\
&=(x-3-\sqrt{2})(x-3+\sqrt{2}).\\
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

You can factor it over $\mathbb R$ as $(x-3-\sqrt2)(x-3+\sqrt2)$!